# Perl WWW::Mechanize: How can I specify the destination IP address independently of the URL?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I want to use Perl www::mechanize to connect to the webserver and request a resource. E.g. http://www.my.domain/test.html. But I want to specify the IP address independently from the hostname in the URL.

For example: [www.my.domain](http://www.my.domain) resolves to 1.1.1.1, but I want to connect to 2.2.2.2.

I want to do this to test multiple web servers behind a load balancer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts);

It works fine with WWW::Mechanize.

```
use LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts;
use WWW::Mechanize;

LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts->register_host('www.my.domain' => '2.2.2.2');
LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts->enable_override;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('http://www.my.domain/test.html'); # connects to 2.2.2.2
```

Comment: I had to add LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts->enable_override; to make it work.

Comment: You're right, I missed that.  Added it to the answer.